# How to test with JUnit, Spring Boot and Flyway?

Tags: junit, flyway

How do i implement Flyway the correct way with Junit?

I added Flyway to my project and put the V1__init.sql (for example) into the `**main**/resources/db/migration` directory. As long as I debug my code (start it without test) it works.

Must I copy the `*.sql` files into the `**test**/resources/db/migration` directory as well ?

I also want, that the tests where made against another database, than test database. Am I correct, that I must add another `application.properties` file under the `test` folder where I put in the credentials for the build-database (where the tests run against?).

Would be really happy if some one could help me out understanding how to configure it the right way.

[image: Image of where the files where placed.]

Comment: You can use the migrations under the src folder. They will be used when running a @SpringBootTest. Therefore no need to copy them. Further you could use TestContainers to implement integration tests against a real database which will relay on the default application.properties

Comment: I read about the testcontainers, but i did not find them for mysql (only postgres) i may want to have another look, thank you .

I even thought, the it will pick up the *.sql files from the main folder, but actually i am getting an error, that it could not found the migration files. I will update my question, may there is an error placing them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can leave the migration files under src and do not need to copy them to your test folder. They are going to be used when running a `@SpringBootTest`. This also ensures that you are using all your `production` migrations for your testing

Further, you don't necessarily need a separate properties file for testing. But you can have one.

Following is an example for IntegrationTesting using `TestContainers` which uses the `application.properties` and also the Flyway migrations in order for the test to behave as you would normally run the application.

This is an abstract class which ensures that the tests are running in the whole Spring context so `Flyway` is also involved. Within the initialiser the datasource configuration properties get overriden by the properties from the Database of `TestContainers`. Doing that you directly use the real `application.properties` and simulate a little bit the real ;))

```java
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.NONE)
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = AbstractPostgreSQLTestContainerIT.Initializer.class)
@Testcontainers
public abstract class AbstractPostgreSQLTestContainerIT {
    private static final String POSTGRES_VERSION = "postgres:11.1";
    public static PostgreSQLContainer database;

    static {
        database = new PostgreSQLContainer(POSTGRES_VERSION);
        database.start();
    }

    static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(
                    configurableApplicationContext,
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + database.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + database.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + database.getPassword()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can define your several test classes like following:

```java
class MyIntegrationTest extends AbstractPostgreSQLTestContainerIT { }
```

When running the tests inside this class the SpringBoot application starts and uses the `TestContainers` database.

For my purpose I have also implemented a simple annotation:

```java
void updateFooByExternalIdentifier_DTOProvided_ShouldReturnUpdatedFoo() {}
```

Code

```java
/**
 * Annotation which allows to provide SQL Scripts for a certain IT test.
 * The transactional ensures that data is cleaned up after test.
 */
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Transactional
@Test
@Sql
public @interface TransactionalSQLTest {
    @AliasFor(attribute = "value", annotation = Sql.class)
    String[] value() default {};

    @AliasFor(attribute = "executionPhase", annotation = Sql.class)
    Sql.ExecutionPhase executionPhase() default Sql.ExecutionPhase.BEFORE_TEST_METHOD;
}
```

Using the annotation you can provide the SQL with e.g. sample data for your test.

The pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
    <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
    <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This should be the dependency for MySql

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/mysql -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql</artifactId>
    <version>1.15.3</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! that sunds great, i tested it with MySqlContainer like the code below, but i am getting an error "You do not have the SUPER privilege and binary logging is enabled". Do you know whats the issue could be? 

Docker looks a great thing, i might spending some time learning more about it.

Comment: Are u running under Linux? If I remember correctly then your user you are running your IDE with needs to be added to a specific group. Otherwise the docker container won’t fire up. Further: Do you have docker installed? If not: TestContainers is based on docker so it is essential to have it installed

Comment: i am using MacOs and i installed Docker. When i create the database like         database = new MySQLContainer();
it works, but this constructor is deprecated.

Do i understand correctly, that the docker mysql instance is only for the tests? When developing eg a new View, i should use my localdatabase (so not the same as the tests are using?)

Comment: Sure. You should only use TeatContainers for testing purposes as the database gets deconstructed after your tests. But you can use Docker for a local database.

Comment: wow! thats awesome. It works perfectly :-D Just need to find out how to get the database without using the dprecated Constructor. 

In my application i need some data like "download pathes" and other things which must be in the database, i think its a good way init those data by flyway then the testcontainer will also be filled with those data.

Comment: You can configure initial data e.g. sql file to the TestContainer within the static initialiser. There should be a corresponding mutator method